# AVSS pins in PIC18f46k80

Tags: microcontroller, analog, pic, adc

I'm trying to use ADC module in [PIC18f46k80](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18F66K80%20FAMILY%20Enhanced%20Flash%20MCU%20with%20ECAN%20XLP%20Technology%2030009977G.pdf) and I want to connect VREF- to AVSS. But the problem is that I can't find AVSS pin in this microcontroller:
[image]
Is AVSS the same as VSS here? meaning I simply have to connect VSS to gnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. On the package types which does not have the AVSS and AVDD pins, they are internally connected to VSS/VDD.